# Query multiple tables with main id to match entry_id of other tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query multiple tables to get information from each.

The main table is `wp_connections.id` which has the columns `first_name` and `last_name`.

The `wp_connections.id` matches all the `.entry_id` columns of the other tables.

Here is what I have so far as for my query:

```html
SELECT wp_connections.first_name, wp_connections.last_name, wp_connections.slug, wp_connections.options, wp_connections_phone.number, wp_connections_email.address 
FROM wp_connections, wp_connections_phone, wp_connections_email, wp_connections_address 
WHERE wp_connections.id = wp_connections_phone.entry_id 
&& wp_connections_phone.entry_id = wp_connections_email.entry_id
&& wp_connections_email.entry_id = wp_connections_address.entry_id AND state = 'Ohio' GROUP BY wp_connections.id
```

Is this incorrect or is there another way that's better?

This does show results, but its not showing all the results. I'm not sure if I need to do a join, or what.

Comment: table definition and sample data

Comment: Preferably in the form of valid `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements. Makes it a lot easier to fiddle with the problem and avoids ambiguities. Any decent mysql frontend should be able to export the data in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing some results, but not all, then you probably need a `left join`.  That is, some of the records for Ohio have phone numbers or emails that are missing:

```
SELECT w.first_name, w.last_name, w.slug, w.options,
       w_phone.number, w_email.address 
FROM wp_connections w INNER JOIN
     wp_connections_address w_address 
     on w.id = w_address.entry_id LEFT JOIN
     wp_connections_phone w_phone
     on w.id = w_phone.entry_id LEFT JOIN
     wp_connections_email w_email
     on w.id = w_email.entry_id
WHERE w_address.state = 'Ohio';
```

Your final `GROUP BY` doesn't do anything, unless some of the record have multiple entries in one or more tables.

Comment: Yes, I am seeing some results, but not all, when I use this no results show.

Comment: @Anthony . . . You should have seen an error.  One of the `LEFT JOIN`s was on the wrong row.

Comment: Perfect, now I am getting some duplicates. I am just pulling the first and last name for now will echo the rest later, but some of the names are duplicating.

Comment: @Anthony . . . If you don't care about which phone number and email address you get, you can just put the `group by` back in.

Comment: Yeah, I think for now thats best, but what would you suggest I look into so I wouldn't have to use the `group by`

Comment: You can use `group_concat()` to combine all the values together.  Or, decide which one you want when there are duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87729/discussion-between-anthony-and-gordon-linoff).